# VBA for each loop not doing the correct action

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

i have this code it's supposed to loop thrugh all the rows in a specific range and if the condition is satisfied it should delete the entire row.

```
Sub zakat()
Dim cell As Range
Dim last As String

Sheets("payment sheet").Activate

Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

last = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Debug.Print (last)

For Each cell In Range("M2:M" & last)

If cell.Text Like "*4435*" Or cell.Text Like "*1292*" Or cell.Text Like "*1293*" Then

cell.Select
Selection.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


End If
Next cell


End Sub
```

I just tried to highlight with yellow color if the condition is satisfied without deleting the transactions just to test if it is looping through all the records and identifying them all correctly, and it did highlight all of them with no issues. just when I ask it to delete the rows it doesn't delete all of them it deletes almost half of hem only!

any suggestions?

Comment: When you are deleting rows then iterate from last to first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting cells you iterate over in a loop always leads to problems. As soon as you delete the first one, you mess up the referencing of all subsequent ones.

A better solution I found is to iterate via index, by counting *backwards* - That way, the subsequent references are not affected.

```vb
For i = last To 1 Step -1
  If .... Then 
    Cells(i,1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
  End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a common difficulty that most of us have fallen foul of at some time!
When deleting a row, generally all rows below it shift up. However, a loop will move onto the 'next' row, rather than checking the row that replaced the one it deleted.
To overcome this, run your loops backwards starting from the bottom, as follows:

```
For a = Last to 2 Step -1 
    If Range("M" & a) Like "*4435*" Or _
        Range("M" & a) Like "*1292*" Or _
        Range("M" & a) Like "*1293*" Then _
    Rows(a).Delete shift:=xlUp
Next
```